# What is the preferred way of running two methods containing infinite loops concurrently using threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to combine two python3 scripts I'm running separately at the moment. Both run in an infinite loop. I found different ways of achieving what I want, but I'm a beginner still learning and trying to do it the right way.

One script is a reddit bot that replies to certain comments and uploads videos, while saving links in newly created .txt files. The other one iterates through those .txt files, reads them and sometimes deletes them.

This variety seems to be the most intuitive for me:

```py
from threading import Thread

def runA():
    while True:
        print 'A\n'

def runB():
    while True:
        print 'B\n'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Thread(target = runA)
    t2 = Thread(target = runB)
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t2.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    while True:
        pass
```

Is this the preferred way of running threads? And why do I need

```
While True:
    pass
```

at the end?

Comment: the `threading` module is somewhat depricated. I would use the [multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) module, or the [pm4py](http://pm4py.org/). Do the processes need to return data to some other process, run as daemons, or receive input?

Comment: It seems that creating two threads will do what you want, but remember that you still have the main thread running. Perhaps you mean t1.join() ; t2.join()

Comment: @RightmireM Threading is not deprecated! Threading and multiprocessing are two different things and each is better for their own set of applications.

Comment: @zvone Well, threading jumps threads back and forth on a single core, no matter how many cores the processor has. multiprocessing uses true multiprocessing. Simply put, multiprocessing can do everything threading can (including running on a single core processor, if you can find one) but threading can't do everything multiprocessing can. What advantages are there to using threading, that you can't get with multiprocessing?

Comment: @RightmireM Both processes and threads exist for decades and whole books can be read about them. What I would single out is that sharing data between threads is much easier than sharing data between processes. And what you wrote about threads is partially correct in Python due to GIL (and depends on what the threads are actually doing), but in many cases does not make a difference (which again depends on what the threads are actually doing).

Comment: @RightmireM One script is a reddit bot that replies to certain comments and uploads videos, while saving links in .txt files. The other one loops through those .txt files, reads them and sometimes deletes them. I guess that means they run as daemons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, that is a good way to start two threads, but there are details to think about.

Note that in that code, there are actually 3 threads: main thread, t1 and t2.

Since the comments say one thread downloads and the other reads the downloaded files and since the main thread does nothing in your case, I'd say you need just this much:

```
def download_forever():
    while True:
        download_stuff()


def process_new_downloads():
    do_something_with_new_downloads_here


def main():
    download_thread = Thread(target=download_forever)
    download_thread.start()
    while True:
        process_new_downloads()
        sleep(1)  # let go of the CPU for a while, there's nothing to do anyway
```

Setting the threads as daemon does not modify how they live, only how they die. And here it is not clear how the whole thing ends, so I'm not sure you need that. You might want to implement some ways to stop the threads politely. You might also define some way to end the whole thing.

Additionaly, you could implement a way for one thread to wake up the other exactly when there is something new to do. You can do that e.g. with a [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects).

BTW, the `while True` which was in the main thread in the original code was needed exactly because all other threads were daemons, so ending the main thread (i.e. not making it run forever) would kill the whole application.